# Save state in OnDeactivateAsync

Tags: azure-service-fabric

My Service Fabric actor can create some large data structure in memory during its work. I don't want to update reliable collection at the end of each method invocation.
Can I save my actor state by StateManager only in OnDeactivateAsync method and restore it in OnActivateAsync method? May I lose the state in this case?

Comment: Are you worrying that garbage collector could collect variables stored in actor object that is not inside actor's state? Or are you unsure about possibility to changes state in OnDeactivateAsync and OnActivateAsync?

Comment: @cassandrad I know that it's possible to save state in OnDeactivateAsync but is it a recommended place in code to save state? I previously saved state every time it's changed but I suppose this approach can create inefficient load on cluster when method invocations are frequent and state size is large.

Comment: You'll lose data if an actor, or its underlying service, or the node crashes. If you can afford to loose state or can rebuild it at Actor ActivateAsync you can just keep that structure as a class member. (like in a regular poco)

Comment: @LoekD that's pretty much spot on, you should post it as the answer.

Comment: The itellisense tooltip tells "Actor operations like state change should not be called from this method". and i also experience inconsistent behavior when doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll lose data if an actor, or its underlying service, or the node crashes. If you can afford to loose state or can rebuild it at Actor ActivateAsync you can just keep that structure as a class member. (like in a regular poco)

(posted as anwser)